# PHP proxy only functioning at certain URLs

Tags: php, tomcat, proxy, amazon-ec2, openlayers

I am trying to get around the cross-domain issue involved in hosting Geoserver map layers on one domain and an html file accessing them via OpenLayers WMSGetFeatureInfo on [another domain](http://greengeography.org/projects/oregonwild/or_wild_webmap18.html). This works fine, of course, when the [html file is on the same domain](http://50.112.123.161:8080/geoserver/www/or_wild_webmap5.html) (click on a polygon, you should get a popup with that feature's info). I've seen a few similar posts on this site and others, but none solved this problem:

When I submit a URL that includes my php proxy, such as http://greengeography.org/projects/oregonwild/curlproxy3.php?url=http://www.google.com, it works fine. But when I try any URL from my Amazon EC2 site (running Linux and Tomcat 6 btw), such as http://greengeography.org/projects/oregonwild/curlproxy3.php?url=http://50.112.123.161:8080, I get a 0 as a result. And that IP address is accessible just fine [on its own](http://50.112.123.161:8080).

Here is my php (I've tried the **get_file_contents** method as well):

```
<?php

    $url = $_REQUEST["url"];

    $curl = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            'POST HTTP/1.0',
            'Content-type: text/xml;charset="UTF-8"',
            'Accept: text/xml',
            'Cache-Control: no-cache',
            'Pragma: no-cache'
        ));
    $theData = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);

    echo $theData;

?>
```

And my OpenLayers/GeoExt:

```
OpenLayers.ProxyHost = "curlproxy3.php?url=";

var featureInfo = new OpenLayers.Control.WMSGetFeatureInfo({
         url: 'http://50.112.123.161:8080/geoserver/OR_wild_wkspc/wms',
         queryVisible: true,  
         FEATURE_COUNT: 1,
         exceptions: "application/vnd.ogc.se_xml",       
         layerUrls: ["http://50.112.123.161:8080/geoserver/gwc/service/wms"],
            eventListeners: {
                getfeatureinfo: function(e) {
                     new GeoExt.Popup({
                     title: "Feature Info",
                     width: 400,
                     autoHeight: true,
                     autoScroll: true,
                     queryVisible: true,
                     map: map,
                     lonlat: mapPanel.map.getLonLatFromPixel(e.xy),
                     html: e.text
                    }).show();
                }
            }
    });

mapPanel.map.addControl(featureInfo);
featureInfo.activate();
```

Also, and apologies as this is a bit of a side issue that I can't even address until I get the proxy working, but when I click on a feature on the main site, I receive the following: **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of null**. Have not been able to figure that one out either.

Any thoughts? I'm thinking it's a problem with Tomcat or some setting in my Linux/Amazon environment and not the php as I have no problem with the proxy pointing to other sites. Oh and I have very little php experience, so please dumb it down if possible. Thanks!